# how to decide input and output shape in DepthwiseConv2D (CNN) in tensroflow Python

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

My actual concern is how to choose input and output based on the data I have.

The shape of data is following for x and y -: `((90000, 6), (90000,))`. and there are two labels in y.

**My data is in CSV file(i am using 6 columns as features, and last column as Label), i am not using IMAGE data**

```
model=models.Sequential()

model.add(tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding='valid', depth_multiplier=10, input_shape=(,)))

# 2 Max Pooling layers  and 1 DepthwiseConv2d
model.add(layers.Flatten())

model.add(layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(2,activation='softmax'))
```

Can someone tell me how to decide Input shape and what kind of reshaping i should do on data before passing it into the Model?

I am looking for suggestions that how can I decide the Input shape and what should i take care of.

also, let me know if the last layer is correct.

I already posted one problem related to this, but this more simplified version of what i actually want to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused here with the implementation, why are you using two dimensional CNN's? You can use tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv1D?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', input_shape=(x.shape[1],x.shape[2])))
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I think something like that might solve your problem.

Comment: no no! i have to use DepthwiseCNN. i just updated the question.